# Error while adding a Custom Local plugin in Cordova project

Tags: cordova, plugins, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have created a Cordova App (for windows) in VS 2015. This App is expected to use a plugin to access functionalities implemented in managed code (C#). I have created a plugin per the expected architecture.

Now, I get an error while adding plugin jn Cordova App using

```
Config -> Plugins-> Custom -> Local ->
```

Full output for `Apache Cordova Tools` is:

```
------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
Installing plugin 'D:\Learning\WindowsApp\Window 10\TestPlugin\MTIFirstCalculator'
Starting launch process C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9\node.exe "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\pluginInstall.js" --action install --projectSourceDir "D:\Learning\WindowsApp\Window 10\FirstCordovaApp\FirstCordovaApp" --pluginName D:\Learning\WindowsApp\Window 10\TestPlugin\MTIFirstCalculator --language en-US  --cliVersion "6.1.1" --npmInstallDir "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm"  --loglevel warn  
------ Cordova tools 6.1.1 already installed.
Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
Executing "before_plugin_add"  hook for all plugins.
No version specified, retrieving version from config.xml
No version given in config.xml, attempting to use plugin engine info
C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/FirstCordovaApp
    at makeError (C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.1.1\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:302:12)
    at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.1.1\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:280:14)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.1.1\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:210:14)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.1.1\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:187:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.1.1\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1044:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\6.1.1\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:965:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
Done
```

The content of plugin.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin id="MTIFirstCalc" version="0.2.0" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0">
    <name>MTIFirstCalc</name>
    <description>Calculator</description>
    <license>MTI</license>
    <keywords></keywords>
    <repo></repo>
    <issue></issue>

    <js-module src="www/MTIFirstCalc.js" name="MTIFirstCalc">
        <clobbers target="window.MTICalculate" />
    </js-module>

    <!-- windows -->
    <platform name="windows">
        <js-module src="src/windows/MTIFirstCalcProxy.js" name="MTIFirstCalcProxy">
            <merges target="" />
        </js-module>

    </platform>

</plugin>
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: What is your plugin's name? Could you post the full error message?

Comment: Name of the plugin is MTIFirstCalc. The Id for plugin is defined as com.MTI.MTIFirstCalc in xml. I have edited OP to include full output for `Apache Cordova tools` from VS2015.

Comment: I just tried your plugin id it works fine, could you please post your `plugin.xml`?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I have added content of plugin.xml. Please note that I tried another plugin (created by another person) using `local` option and it didnt work either.

Comment: Thanks @ElvisXia-MSFT. Finally I could resolve the issue. Seems a bug/limitation of `Apache Cordova Tools`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could resolve the problem. I'm not sure if its a bug OR limitation of `Apache Cordova Tools`.

The actual problem was in the path where plugin directory was created. Perhaps `space` is not allowed in name of folders leading to plugin's location.

My plugin was kept in `D:\Learning\WindowsApp\Window 10\TestPlugin\MTIFirstCalculator` folder.

I could add plugin once I changed the path to `D:\Learning\WindowsApp\Window10\TestPlugin\MTIFirstCalculator`

Please note that space is removed in `Window10` folder.

The bug is present even in Cordova tools 6.5.0.